# Why doesn't my multi processor program take the whole path of my image?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-tesseract

I've been trying to use multiprocessing on a program that uses tesseract to extract text from images. But when I give the name to my image, it only searches for the first letter of the name of the image in the directory

```
def tess(all_clips):
    img_text={}
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    image_dirs=[]
    for a in all_clips:
        image_dirs.append(Image.open('E:/fin_100_images/'+a))
    num=0
    for img in image_dirs:
        df_temp = pytesseract.image_to_data(img,lang='mar',output_type='data.frame')
        df_temp=df_temp.dropna().drop(['level', 'page_num', 'par_num', 'line_num', 'word_num','conf'],axis=1).reset_index().drop('index',1)
        img_text[img] = df_temp.T.to_dict()
        print('Total images done: '+str(num+1)+'\t Total images remaining: '+str(len(all_clips)-num-1)+'        ',end='\r')

        num=num+1

    stop = timeit.default_timer()

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(list(img_text.items()), columns=['name', 'word_detail'])
    print('Time: ', stop - start)
    return df_temp


if __name__=='__main__':
    all_clips = list(set([f for f in listdir('E:/fin_100_images/') if isfile(join('E:/fin_100_images/', f))]))
    processes=[]

    for i in all_clips:
        process = Process(target=tess, args=(i,))
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print("Multiprocessing complete")
```

I'm getting the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/fin_100_images/l'
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PRATHAMESH\Desktop\TEST_multi.py", line 28, in tess
    image_dirs.append(Image.open('E:/fin_100_images/'+a))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2770, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
```

Comment: Your problem most likely comes from looping twice over your all_clips - ones when you start the processes and then inside your `tess`  function as well. But at the moment there you get only a single string and no longer a list. And if you loop over a string you iterate over the letters. Hence you see the first letter... - Also you might want to look into process pool

Comment: @Lutz Thanks. That's what I was missing